# Open a vine url in vine app using vine://

Tags: ios, vine

I'm trying to open up the vine app when you tap a vine url from my app. Doing

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"vine://http://vine.co/v/biTaEEwdq2n?1"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Will indeed open up the app, but not navigate to the video. Any idea how this is done? Is it possible?

Comment: Unless vine has any documentation on the `vice:` schema I guess no one  will be able to answer this.

Comment: Vine does not have a documentation on this. The URL Scheme `vine://` indeed will open Vine app, but there is no docs about what to pass as parameters.

Comment: shucks, do you know if vimeo has any documentation?

Comment: @GabeJacobs there is nothing on the vine website, so I guess there is no doucmentation. You try and ask then if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the Javascript on vine.co, I've found that the correct scheme for a post is : `vine://post/<#id#>` . So, let's try this `vine://post/biTaEEwdq2n`

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vine://v/biTaEEwdq2n` or `vine://video/biTaEEwdq2n` as the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The URL Scheme for the vine profile page is vine://user/USERID

Ex:
vine://user/126850376482649253